# Undoing createDataPartition ordering

Tags: r, predict

I'm new to data science and trying to finish up this project. I have a data frame (from here https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) with assigned train and test sets (1:1460, 1461:2919) that I was suggested to use createDataPartition() on due to an error I was getting when trying to predict

```
> predSale <- as.data.frame(predict(model, newdata = test))
  Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = 
   object$xlevels) : factor MSSubClass has new levels 150
```

But now when using createDataPartition, it's mixing up my original train and test sets, which I need in a specific order for the Kaggle submission. I've read in the vignette and looks like there is an argument for returnTrain. I'm not sure if this could be used (I don't fully understand it), but ultimately I'd like to know if there is a way to undo the ordering so I can submit my project with the original ordered set.

```
test$SalePrice <- NA
combined <- rbind(train, test)

train <- combined[1:1460, ]
test <- combined[1461:2919, ]

#____________Models____________

set.seed(666)
index <- createDataPartition(paste(combined$MSSubClass,combined$Neighborhood,
                               combined$Condition2,combined$LotConfig,
                               combined$Exterior1st,combined$Exterior2nd,
                               combined$RoofMatl,combined$MiscFeature,combined$SaleType))$Resample
train <- combined[index,]
test <- combined[-index,]


model <- lm(SalePrice ~., train)

predSale <- as.data.frame(predict(model, newdata = test))

SampleSubmission <- round(predSale, digits = 1)
write.csv(SampleSubmission, "SampleSubmission.csv")
```

Thanks!! If there is anything you need answered please let me know,I think I've provided  everything (I'm not sure if you need the full code or what, I'll be happy to edit with whatever more needed)?

Comment: if the problem is the order, I guess you could use `dplyr::arrange` to sort your predictions as the original dataset.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up having to do in the long run. I still had issues after the createDataPartition with one of the variables. I ended up just removing it from the data set for now until I can create a better solution (luckily it wasn't highly important).

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `createDataPartition` on a combined kaggle dataset. You need to keep these data sets separate. That's why kaggle provides them. If you want to combine them, then you have to split them again as they were after you have done your data cleaning.

But the issue you have is that there are factor levels in the test dataset that are not seen by the model. There are multiple posts on kaggle about this issue. But I must say that kaggle's search engines is crappy.

In kaggle competitions some people use the following code on character columns to turn them into numeric (e.g. for using the data with xgboost). This code assumes that you loaded the data sets with stringAsFactors = False.

```
for (f in feature.names) {
    if (class(train[[f]])=="character") {
    levels <- unique(c(train[[f]], test[[f]]))
    test[[f]]  <- as.integer(factor(test[[f]],  levels=levels))
    train[[f]] <- as.integer(factor(train[[f]], levels=levels))
    }
}
```

Others use a version of the following to create all the level names in the training data set.

```
levels(xtrain[,x]) <- union(levels(xtest[,x]),levels(xtrain[,x]))
```

There are more ways of dealing with this.

Of course these solutions are nice for Kaggle, as this might give you a better score. But in a strict sense this is a sort of data leakage. And using this in a production setting, is asking for trouble. There are many situations in which you might not know all of the possible values in advance, and when encountering a new value returning a missing value instead of a prediction is a more sensible choice. But that discussion fills complete research articles.

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct. I wouldn't have used this except I was told to use it to fix the factor issue (which I'm still not sure I fully understand). I didn't search kaggle for info on this, I'll check it out there and see what I can find too thanks!

Thanks for the suggestions too. This was my first project(and a rather larger one than I needed lol) and as such, there were a lot of mistakes early on that made things more difficult (such as how I loaded things etc.). I'll have to see what I can do with that 2nd set of code. I'll work with that, thanks